# Finding the direction of the electric field of several charges?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

A clock has negative charges -q, -2q, -3q,...., -12q fixed at a the position of the corresponding numerals on the dial. The clock hands do not disturb the electric net electric field due to pont charges. At what times does the hour hand point in the direction of the electric field at the centre of the dial?

Comment: You need to do vector addition of the fields due to each charge. Which specific bit are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Taking opposite hands we always get a difference of 6 so paiwise resolving we would have 6 resultant vectors as shown, and each will be 6 unit.So by symmetry(you can calculate and check it) the clock will point at $9:30$.